# using Mathf.Clamp in Vector3 to restrict object drag

Tags: unity, c#

I'm making a checkers game and I've got a movement controller working to move the pieces. I want to restrict the drag to be within the board. The center of the board is 0,0 so the far left side's x value is -4, top of the boards y is 4, etc...

This is my drag script so far

```
void OnMouseDrag()
{
        float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen));
}
```

but when I try to clamp my new Vector3's x and y between -4 and 4 like this,

```
transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(Input.mousePosition.x,-4f,4f), Mathf.Clamp(Input.mousePosition.y,-4f,4f), distance_to_screen));
```

it shoots the pieces way off camera. This may be because don't truly understand Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint, is it returning different x,y coordinates than the global ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your bounds (-4,-4) -> (4, 4) are world space coordinates, your error is that you're clamping the input (screen space) instead of the output of `ScreenToWorldPoint`.

`Input.mousePosition` will give you pixel coordinates between (0,0) and the max resolution of your screen (`Screen.width`, `Screen.height`).

Try clamping the result *after* the call to `ScreenToWorldPoint`:

```
void OnMouseDrag() {
    float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
    Vector3 before_clamp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(
        Input.mousePosition.x,
        Input.mousePosition.y,
        distance_to_screen));
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(before_clamp.x, -4, 4),
        Mathf.Clamp(before_clamp.y, -4, 4),
        before_clamp.z);
}
```

Comment: Yup that was it, works perfectly. Thank you so much.